# Spring MVC Test Dirties a *Different* ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I'm working on an Application using Spring MVC 4.0.4 and Hibernate, and we're using Spring Test MVC 1.0.0.M2 to do some integration/unit tests. We use HSQLDB as an in-memory DB during these tests and have Hibernate create the schema (`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is `create`). I've got a problem with a setup that's sort of like the following:

There are three test classes: A, B, C. They all use the database and are executed in that order. It's essentially this:

Test A and C:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "/configuration/someBeanConfig",
        "/configuration/someDatabaseConfig.xml",
})
@WebAppConfiguration()
public class SomeTest {
  // ... Tests
}
```

Test B:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    // Configs and test data sets:
    SomeDatabaseConfig.class,
    SomeOtherConfig.class,
    // Actual beans used:
    SomeBean.class,
    AnotherBean.class,
})
public class DifferentTest {
  // ... Tests
}
```

According to [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-ctx-management), since the ApplicationContext config of A and C are equal, they share a cached ApplicationContext. B has a different context. However, it still uses the same database.

Here is the problem:

- Test B does some things that pollute the database, causing Test C to fail.
- According to [this Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) I can use the `@DirtiesContext` annotation to tell Spring that a test does something bad to the ApplicationContext and that Spring should re-initialize it upon next use.
- Putting `@DirtiesContext` on Test B will not work, because it's not context B that should be fixed, it's also that of A and C. Putting it on Test B won't make Spring re-initialize that of Test C.
- I could put `@DirtiesContext` on Test A. Then, when it's time to run Test C, Spring will create the new ApplicationContext from scratch. However, if the order of tests ever changes, or we add tests with the same ApplicationContexts and they're run in between these, the problem would just re-occur. All the while the order of unit/integration tests really should not matter. So it's not a permanent solution, and it's also not very elegant.
- I tried setting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to `create-drop` and `update`, but since the ApplicationContext is re-created from scratch, neither is the database schema, and so it doesn't help.

Any suggestions on how to tell Spring that *all* contexts are dirtied (say, `@DirtiesEveryContext`)? Or any other suggestions about how to solve this?